# Laravel Validation Extend Not Firing

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I don't think that my validator extentions are working, but I can't fathom why.

**Service Provider.**

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Validator::extend('fail', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
            return false;
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
    }

}
```

I know the Service Provider's boot is firing because if I `dd();` inside the boot method I get output. If I add a `dd();` to the extend closure function, I do not get any output.

**Request**

```
class SaveOrder extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        $rules = [
            'customer_id' => 'in:' . Customer::getImplodedCurrentTeamKeys(),
            'pin' => 'fail'
        ];

        return $rules;
    }
}
```

I know the request is validating correctly because if I change the rule to `'pin' => 'required'` and don't give in put I get a fail.

Why is my custom validation rule not working?

Comment: This is may be silly, is the namespace `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator` add in the `AppServiceProvider `?

Comment: @Saumini thanks for your reply and your suggestion. Yes `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;` is present at the top of `AppServiceProvider`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found my solution at the very bottom of the Laravel Validation docs page: (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation)

> For a rule to run even when an attribute is empty, the rule must imply that the attribute is required. To create such an "implicit" extension, use the Validator::extendImplicit() method:

By changing the method from `extend` to `extendImplicit` , my problem was solved.

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Validator::extendImplicit('fail', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
            return false;
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
    }

}
```